# Pagination last page and first page php

Tags: php, html

I am new to pagination and have managed to get this:

[image]

Now i want if the page is = 0 it must go back to page 1, and the last page should just be looping

i want the following :

(1) if no page var is given, default to 1.
(2) previous page is page - 1
(3) previous page is page - 1
(4) next page is page + 
(5) last page should be equals to $total_pages

```
   <?php
      $limit = 6;
      if (isset($_GET["page"]))
       {
       $page  = $_GET["page"];
       } else
       {
      $page = 1;
       };

     $total_records = $pagination;
     $total_pages = ceil($total_records/$limit);

     if($page = 0)
     $page = 1;     
     $prev = $page - 1;                          
     $next = $page + 1;                        

      $pagLink = "<ul class='pagination' class='justify-content-center'>";

      $pagLink .= "<li class='page-item'>
      <a class='page-link' href='home.php?page=".$prev."'   aria-label='Back'>
      <span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>
      <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
  </a>
</li>";

  for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  

  $pagLink .= "<li class='page-item'><a  class='page-link'    href='home.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li> ";

   };


     $pagLink .= "<li class='page-item'>
  <a class='page-link' href='home.php?page=".$next."' aria-label='Next'>
    <span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span>
    <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
  </a>
  </li>";
  echo $pagLink . "</ul>";

   ?>
```

Comment: you want to use pagination in table data

Comment: @Ragupathi from mysql database

Comment: @emmanuel so the pagination bar is working, but the result from the database is incorrect? If so, you should show us the queries instead of the code you provided which generates the HTML for the pagination.

Comment: `if($page = 0)` - that is an _assignment_, not a _comparison_. And if you are a beginner, then learn right now to _never_ use if/else without `{ … }` behind them, that is bound to lead you into trouble at some point.

Comment: @misorude thank you for the response and will definitely not make such a mistake again

Comment: @ErikvandeVen yes the pagination bar is working , but if i press the next button its exceding the totalpages number and if i click previous button its taking page 0 as the first page, my question is how can i set  the first page and last page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably be the issue, or at least it is an issue in your code:

```
if($page = 0)
  $page = 1;     
  $prev = $page - 1;                          
  $next = $page + 1;
```

This `=` means assignment, what you are actually saying is that "if assignment of `$page = 0` goes well, do the following... So `$page` is always equal to 1, no matter what. What you actually want is check the variable if it's equal to 0, like this

```
if($page == 0)
  $page = 1;     
  $prev = $page - 1;                          
  $next = $page + 1;
```

See the double `==`